# Extract string with bibliographic data from a .txt file into a dictionary in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dictionary, text-extraction

i want to code a python function, which extracts certain string elements out of a textfile with bibliographical data.
The file contains different lines like that:

```
shakespeare, william: macbeth. novel, second edition, cambridge, 2005
```

Each line is been separated by a `\n`.

How can i extract these lines into a structure like:

```
author : shakespeare, william
title : macbeth
```

usw.

Comment: What have you tried?  For regex-related problems, I have always preferred to use a testing site like [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) and play around with an example input that I'm trying to process.  The real-time results help give a good intuition for how they work.

Comment: that is my code so far:
`import re
def meta_dict():
    with open("bib.txt", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as infile, open("bib.json", "wt", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        content = infile.read()
        line = content.splitlines()
        for single in line:
            author = re.search (r'^[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+|^[A-Z][a-ä]+,\s[A-Z][a-z]+|^[A-Z][a-ü]+|^[A-Z].[A-Z].\s[A-Z][a-z]+|^[A-Z][a-z]*\s[a-z]+|^[A-Z][a-z]+\s[a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+', single)
            print (author)`

Comment: Move the additions into the question body by editing.  They aren't readable in that form.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Every line would have its own dictionary then.

```
d = {}
s = "shakespeare, william: macbeth. novel, second edition, cambridge, 2005"
data = s.split(".")[0].split(": ")
d["author"] = data[0]
d["title"] = data[1]

print d
#Output
{'title': 'macbeth', 'author': 'shakespeare, william'}
```

Comment: Ok, so far so good, but how can i do this for every line? i'd like to have a module with two functions. one to extract the strings, which i figured out with your code above. The second function should do it for every line...